# linker error in c++ and returns null value while geeting the new val function

Tags: c++

I am getting the inconsistent error while i am trying to execute the following program.can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong...

```
int a,b=0;
int getvalue(int c)
 {
    int n=0;
    a=c;
    if(n<c)
    n=a+b;
    return n;
 }
 int newvalue(int c)
 {
 int n=0;
 int a=c;
 if(n<getvalue(c))
 n=a+b;
 return n;
 }
 voidmain()
 {
 int j=1;
 int b=newvalue(j);
 cout<<a+b+j<<end1;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Here's something you might want to look into: `voidmain`.

Comment: You can't have both the problems you claim to have. Can you be more specific about the problem, include any error messages you get, and say what you expect your code to do?

Comment: Also, you declare a local variable `a` inside `newvalue` that shadows the global variable. Is it on purpose? Please post expected and actual results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (end1 should be endl) and I fixed the main signature.

```
#include <iostream>

int a,b=0;
int getvalue(int c)
{
    int n=0;
    a=c;
    if(n<c)
        n=a+b;
    return n;
}

int newvalue(int c)
{
    int n=0;
    int a=c;
    if(n<getvalue(c))
        n=a+b;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int j=1;
    int b=newvalue(j);
    std::cout<<a+b+j<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing I suspect that a space between void and main could help you. voidmain() -> void main(). However if you already can compile the code my advice won't help.